# Heuristic for A* when only diagonal movement is allowed

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I'm planning to use A* algorithm for path finding on a infinite grid with obstacles where only diagonal movements are allowed.But I'm not sure about which heuristic to use.I know that I cannot use Manhattan Distance.Can anyone suggest something ?

Comment: If only diagonal movements are allowed then depending on the starting position, half of the grid is not be reachable. Is it correct? (e.g. bishop in chess)

Comment: @Demplo Yep,you are right.

Comment: Then I would say Tom's answer works fine. Once you know if the target is reachable, you rotate 45 degrees and use Manhattan there. Assuming diagonal moves cost 1.

Comment: @Demplo Got it,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think chess. Rotate 45 degrees. If only diagonal movement is allowed, in effect it's just like a grid with only orthogonal movement, but half the points on the original grid are unreachable.

Comment: Yes,so what heuristic should I use so that it's admissible ?

Comment: @Arun: First see if the target is even reachable. Then transform the coordinates to an ordinary grid, and use whatever heuristic you would use for such a grid.